# Is it safe to resize partition in ext4?

Tags: partition, ext4, disk

I would like to reduce the size of an ext4 partition from my disk and I would like to know if it is possible that my files become corrupted during the operation ? I learn that ext4 file system use large extents for each file, so is it possible that a file is located at the end of the partition and become corrupted/deleted during the process ?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

## Yes, it is safe

As long as the process is not interrupted by i.e. power loss, your data will be fine. This is what `resize2fs` is made for. It will move data around so nothing is lost. it will warn you if you attempt something potentially harmful. I used `resize2fs` numerous times for offline shrinking and never experienced any problems (except human error).

Comment: power loss is not a valid exanple for data loss intteruption, since HDD is primary storage and is non volatile it doesnt remove all data when the powet is lost.

Comment: resize2fs is safe even on power loss.

Comment: @SimonRichter I expeienced it once. Indeed, everything was fine. I assumed I just got lucky.
@Qasim I do not know if `resize2fs` systematically bypasses the disk's write cache. I want to play it safe.

Answer (score 2):

It's possible for things to go wrong. It's hard to rule that possibility out completely. You should always have a backup of your data.

Other than that, it's as safe as it could possibly made to be. It should either just work or display a message that it couldn't be done for some reason or other.

Most data loss regarding ext4 resizes are user errors (did things in wrong order, shrank partition too much, etc.) or unexpected crash or power loss events during critical operations.

So it's deemed quite safe, but still - there's always a risk with in-place data conversions. You have the same risk with other filesystems, with `pvmove` or `mdadm` RAID reshapes, etc. [Murphy's Law](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Murphy's_law) is always lurking around the corner.

Make backups. If your backup isn't up to date, don't take unnecessary risks.